# One Oracle scheduled job runs parallel with another instance. How to prevent this problem?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, jobs

I have a stored Procedure which triggerd by a job every day. Sometimes the procedure takes more time an Oracle scheduler
runs another instance of my procedure. This is a problem. How can i prevent Oracle from starting a new procedure until
the first one is finsish or kill the first one and start the second.

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
      ,start_date      => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021/08/11 09:30:00.000000 Europe/Berlin','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss.ff tzr')
      ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ = DAILY; INTERVAL = 1'
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
      ,job_action      => 'GWANEU.AS_LOESCHEN_JOB_PROCEDURE'
      ,comments        => 'Job, der autom. nach X Jahren die abgemeldeten Arbeitsstätten löscht.'
    );
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'RESTARTABLE'
     ,value     => FALSE);
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'LOGGING_LEVEL'
     ,value     => SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE_NULL
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'MAX_FAILURES');
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE_NULL
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'MAX_RUNS');
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'STOP_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE'
     ,value     => FALSE);
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'JOB_PRIORITY'
     ,value     => 3);
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE_NULL
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'SCHEDULE_LIMIT');
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'AUTO_DROP'
     ,value     => FALSE);
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'RESTART_ON_RECOVERY'
     ,value     => FALSE);
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'RESTART_ON_FAILURE'
     ,value     => FALSE);
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'
     ,attribute => 'STORE_OUTPUT'
     ,value     => TRUE);

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE
    (name                  => 'GWANEU.AS_ABMELDEN_JOB');
END;
/
```

Comment: Following the official Oracle documentation: "Immediately after a job starts, the repeat_interval is evaluated to determine the next scheduled execution time of the job. While this might arrive while the job is still running, a new instance of the job does not start until the current one completes.". So it's not possible to have 2 instances of the same job running at the same time. Maybe you have multiple jobs of the same name in different schemas? Or maybe someone called the procedure manually? How did you get the information that the job started before the previous one finished?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the job is running already at the beginning of your procedure

> GWANEU.AS_LOESCHEN_JOB_PROCEDURE

Just paste that into you procedure.

```
select nvl(max(1), 0)
into   nExists
from   user_scheduler_running_jobs j
where  j.JOB_NAME = 'AS_ABMELDEN_JOB'

-- If job running already
if (nExists = 1) then
  return;
end if;
```